# Auto Logout after session expire

Tags: php

I am working in PHP Website.I want to auto logout features in my website.
auto logout feature based on session expire.once a session expire logout
automatically.
but i can not identify how session expire and how to make logout 
after session expire.
Please help me...

Comment: `if(!$_SESSION){ header('Location: logout.php'); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save in your session the following.

The last time you performed an action  (i did in the example below simply whenever i refreshed the page)

check if the difference between those two is greater than you want the auto time out is. If so, refer then to logout, if not, send to the page requested.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['activiteit']) && (time() - $_SESSION['activiteit'] > 1800)){
         session_unset();     
         session_destroy(); 
         include_once('inc/admin/login.php');
    } else {
        include_once('inc/admin/adminpanel.php');
    }
}else{
    include_once('inc/admin/login.php');
}
$_SESSION['activiteit'] = time();
?>
```

so technically what happens here is that it substracts the activty variable from the time variable. If the difference is larger than 1800, i am destroying and unsetting the session and refer to it the login page. if not, i am refering it to the admin panel. If the user has no session user at all, than its automaticly refered to the login screen.

Hope this helps

Comment: If it answered your problem, please accept it as correct answer, else people might think its not yet solved.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the value of your $_SESSION. If its value is false, redirect to a logout page or execute a function who disconnect the user.